# How to use Refl in a "with" clause

Tags: types, equality, with-statement, idris

I want to prove a fact about the parity of numbers.

I started out with the following definition:

```
data Parity = Even | Odd 

revParity : Parity -> Parity
revParity Even = Odd
revParity Odd = Even

parity : Nat -> Parity
parity Z = Even -- zero is even
parity (S p) = revParity $ parity p -- inverse parity
```

In a lot of cases, i figured out it was simpler to pattern match on the parity, using the "with" syntax.
For example:

```
test: (n:Nat) -> (parity (S n) = Even) -> (parity n = Odd)
test n eq with (parity n)
  test n eq | Odd = Refl
  test n eq | Even impossible
```

But then, I try something very similar :

```
data Prop: Nat -> Type where
  FromPar: {n: Nat} -> (parity n = Odd) -> Prop n

test2: (n: Nat) -> (parity (S n) = Even) -> Prop n
test2 n eq with (parity n)
  test2 n eq | Odd = FromPar Refl
```

I know that in the branch the types of `parity n` and `Odd` are the same, but I can't create an element of type `parity n = Odd`.

I get the following error:

> While processing right hand side of with block in test2. Can't solve constraint between:
> Odd and parity n.

Is there something I am doing wrong ?
Can I create a Refl in this "with" branch ?

Is it possible to use this technique or do I have to use "rewrite" or define another function instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [bring in scope a proof that `parity n = Odd`](https://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/views.html#with-and-proofs), because otherwise after you pattern match on its result, its connection to `parity n` is lost:

> To use a dependent pattern match for theorem proving, it is sometimes
> necessary to explicitly construct the proof resulting from the pattern
> match. To do this, you can postfix the `with` clause with `proof p`
> and the proof generated by the pattern match will be in scope and
> named `p`.

So in your case, you can do this:

```
test2: (n: Nat) -> (parity (S n) = Even) -> Prop n
test2 n eq with (parity n) proof p
  test2 n eq | Odd = FromPar p
```